# When are $\{\mathbf{0}\}$ and $V$ the only subspaces of a vector space $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I think it is when the dimension of $V$ is either $1$ or $0$. I think I have to do some proof by contradiction (in case we can set dim $V \geq 2$ for deriving the contradiction), but I do not know how to start. Could you give me a hint, please?

Comment: You are correct, vector space $V$ has the trivial subspace as its only proper subspace exactly when the dimension of $V$ is $1$.  Of course $V=0$ has no proper subspace.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is correct. Now, as to how to prove it: if $V$ has dimension $\ge 2$, we can find a set $\{u, v\}$ of vectors which are linearly independent (if $V$'s dimension is $>2$ this won't be a basis, but I'm not demanding that it be a basis - only that it be linearly independent).

Now, do you see how to construct a subspace which is neither $\{0\}$ nor $V$, using this? *HINT: it would be enough for the subspace to contain $u$ but not $v$, do you see why?*

Comment: Is it because it is a basis of some subspace $U \subseteq V$?

Comment: @TheBosco Sort of. But be more direct - can you describe for me a *specific* subspace of $V$ which contains $u$ but not $v$?

Comment: Is it $\{0, u\}$  ?

Comment: @TheBosco That's probably not a subspace! (Your field of scalars is probably $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, so either way "${1\over 2}u$" would have to be in any subspace containing $u$, do you see why?)

Comment: Is it the subspace that contains all elements $\alpha u$, where $\alpha$ is a scalar?

Comment: @TheBosco Yes, that's exactly it! (Otherwise denoted "$\langle u\rangle$", usually.) But you have to prove it - do you see how to show that this space is neither $\{0\}$ or $V$?

Comment: Well, $0 < dim \langle u \rangle < 2$. Thus $dim\ u \neq dim\ \{0\}$ or $dim\ V$. Thus, they cannot be the same set.

Comment: @TheBosco There you go! And this can be done without even referring to dimension: since $\{u,v\}$ is linearly independent, we have $u\not=0$; so since $u\in\langle u\rangle$, $\langle u\rangle\not=\{0\}$. Also, since $\{u, v\}$ is linearly independent we can't have $v\in\langle u\rangle$, so $\langle u\rangle\not=V$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55250/discussion-between-the-bosco-and-noah-schweber).